# Looping through an array of objects only returning 1 object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, and when looping through them I am only able to return 1 object..

Room A

Area 1

Area 5

Area 19

Then throws an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AreaName' of undefined

Not sure why I am only returning 1 object and not the rest and then getting that error

```js
(function() {

  function RoomsList() {
    let rooms = [{
        RoomID: 1,
        RoomName: "Room A",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 11,
          AreaName: "Area 1"
        }, {
          AreaID: 15,
          AreaName: "Area 5"
        }, {
          AreaID: 19,
          AreaName: "Area 19"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 2,
        RoomName: "Room B",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 12,
          AreaName: "Area 2"
        }, {
          AreaID: 16,
          AreaName: "Area 6"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 3,
        RoomName: "Room C",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 13,
          AreaName: "Area 3"
        }, {
          AreaID: 17,
          AreaName: "Area 7"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 4,
        RoomName: "Room D",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 14,
          AreaName: "Area 4"
        }, {
          AreaID: 18,
          AreaName: "Area 8"
        }]
      }
    ];
    return rooms;
  }

  var roomAndAreasObject = RoomsList();

  for (let i = 0; i < roomAndAreasObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(roomAndAreasObject[i].RoomName);
    for (let j = 0; j < roomAndAreasObject.length; j++) {
      console.log(roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas[j].AreaName);
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your second loop is wrong. Try `roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested `for` loop should be checking against the length of the current object's `Areas` property, rather than the length of the entire array.

```
for (let j = 0; j < roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas.length; j++) {
```

```js
(function() {

  function RoomsList() {
    let rooms = [{
        RoomID: 1,
        RoomName: "Room A",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 11,
          AreaName: "Area 1"
        }, {
          AreaID: 15,
          AreaName: "Area 5"
        }, {
          AreaID: 19,
          AreaName: "Area 19"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 2,
        RoomName: "Room B",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 12,
          AreaName: "Area 2"
        }, {
          AreaID: 16,
          AreaName: "Area 6"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 3,
        RoomName: "Room C",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 13,
          AreaName: "Area 3"
        }, {
          AreaID: 17,
          AreaName: "Area 7"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 4,
        RoomName: "Room D",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 14,
          AreaName: "Area 4"
        }, {
          AreaID: 18,
          AreaName: "Area 8"
        }]
      }
    ];
    return rooms;
  }

  var roomAndAreasObject = RoomsList();

  for (let i = 0; i < roomAndAreasObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(roomAndAreasObject[i].RoomName);
    for (let j = 0; j < roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas.length; j++) {
      console.log(roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas[j].AreaName);
    }

  }

})();
```

Comment: I'll accept as answer when able to. Even though Sysix gave a comment that contained the correction that was needed, but you answered and gave an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the maximum value of `j` in your inner loop:

```js
(function() {

  function RoomsList() {
    let rooms = [{
        RoomID: 1,
        RoomName: "Room A",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 11,
          AreaName: "Area 1"
        }, {
          AreaID: 15,
          AreaName: "Area 5"
        }, {
          AreaID: 19,
          AreaName: "Area 19"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 2,
        RoomName: "Room B",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 12,
          AreaName: "Area 2"
        }, {
          AreaID: 16,
          AreaName: "Area 6"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 3,
        RoomName: "Room C",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 13,
          AreaName: "Area 3"
        }, {
          AreaID: 17,
          AreaName: "Area 7"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 4,
        RoomName: "Room D",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 14,
          AreaName: "Area 4"
        }, {
          AreaID: 18,
          AreaName: "Area 8"
        }]
      }
    ];
    return rooms;
  }

  var roomAndAreasObject = RoomsList();

  for (let i = 0; i < roomAndAreasObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(roomAndAreasObject[i].RoomName);
    for (let j = 0; j < roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas.length; j++) {
      console.log(roomAndAreasObject[i].Areas[j].AreaName);
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or to avoid these kinds of errors, you can use the `for...of` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
(function() {

  function RoomsList() {
    let rooms = [{
        RoomID: 1,
        RoomName: "Room A",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 11,
          AreaName: "Area 1"
        }, {
          AreaID: 15,
          AreaName: "Area 5"
        }, {
          AreaID: 19,
          AreaName: "Area 19"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 2,
        RoomName: "Room B",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 12,
          AreaName: "Area 2"
        }, {
          AreaID: 16,
          AreaName: "Area 6"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 3,
        RoomName: "Room C",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 13,
          AreaName: "Area 3"
        }, {
          AreaID: 17,
          AreaName: "Area 7"
        }]
      },
      {
        RoomID: 4,
        RoomName: "Room D",
        Areas: [{
          AreaID: 14,
          AreaName: "Area 4"
        }, {
          AreaID: 18,
          AreaName: "Area 8"
        }]
      }
    ];
    return rooms;
  }

  var roomAndAreasObject = RoomsList();

  for (const areasObject of roomAndAreasObject) {
    console.log(areasObject.RoomName);
    for (const area of areasObject.Areas) {
      console.log(area.AreaName);
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```